# Lodash's "without" by property and input array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I would like to make a function using lodash's "without", using object property and array of values. Similar to "include"

My **"_.include()"** function code is:

```
 this.filters = {} //hold filter function for one or many columns in table
 this.columnName = 'id'

 this.tempQuery = [1,2]

 this.data = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'aaa',
  rejectedNumber: 1
 },  
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bbb',
  rejectedNumber: 2
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: 'bbb',
  rejectedNumber: 3
 }
]

 this.filters[this.columnName] = _.partial(_.includes, this.tempQuery);

 this.filteredData = _.filter( this.data, _.conforms( this.filters ));
```

And my output is

```
 this.filteredData = [ 
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'aaa',
  rejectedNumber: 1
 },  
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bbb',
  rejectedNumber: 2
 }]
```

But i can't do something similar with "_.without" function

```
this.filters[this.columnName] = _.partial(_.without, this.tempQuery);
```

Not working - return all data...

Any ideas how to make query using lodash functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you cannot just replace `_.includes` with `_.without` is that they are not each other's opposite. They have in common that the first argument they take can be an array (which is what you use for it). But there the similarity ends; they are quite different:

- `_.includes` returns a **boolean** indicating whether the second argument occurs in the array
- `_.without` returns a **array** that includes the values in the original array except the second argument (and other argument values if provided).

As an array is always a truthy value, the `_.conform` function -- when based on `_.without` -- will always return true.

Instead of `_.without`, create the real opposite of `_.includes` with `_.negate`:

```
this.filters[this.columnName] = _.partial(_.negate(_.includes), this.tempQuery);
```

I suppose that you do not want to touch the use of `_.filter`, but just as an alternative, you could also negate that with `_.reject`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Best solution for me.

Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to iterate over your collection using `_.filter` and then return either a truthy/falsey value based on what you want filtered. `_.includes` will do a check to see if the value passed exists in the collection that is given. You can then filter out your collection this way as `_.filter` will return a new array.

Pen: https://codepen.io/joshuakelly/pen/aPgLmL

```
const tempQuery = [1, 2];
const data = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'aaa',
  rejectedNumber: 1
 },  
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bbb',
  rejectedNumber: 2
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: 'bbb',
  rejectedNumber: 3
 }
];

const withFilteredData = _.filter(data, col => _.includes(tempQuery, col.id));
const withoutFilteredData = _.filter(data, col => !_.includes(tempQuery, col.id));

console.log(withFilteredData, withoutFilteredData);
```